# Apparent contradiction in the definition of Fermi-level

Tags: semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

The fermi level in an intrinsic semiconductor is defined as $$E_F = (E_c + E_v)/2 + kT/q \ln (Nv/Nc).$$ From this equation, the position of fermi level is exactly at the center of the band gap at 0K.
On the other hand, fermi level is defined as the highest occupied energy level at 0K, which would be the top of the valence band in an intrinsic semiconductor.
What is the reason for this apparent contradiction? Is it because it is impossible to achieve 0K?

Comment: One definition is for a metal, one is for a semi-conductor

Comment: metal has density of states at the fermi level, semi-conductor doesnt

Comment: also it's better to say chemical potential. fermi level, fermi energy are terms usually reserved for metals

Comment: Why is the definition for metals not valid for semiconductors?

Comment: The Fermi function determines the probability that an energy level may be occupied. The density of states of those levels provides all the states that could be occupied. The combination yields which states are occupied with what probability. Since there are no states in the gap of a semiconductor, it does not matter what the Fermi function is - there are no states to occupy. Note that such things can also happen in real metals, especially for occupancy at a given $k$ vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct definition of the Fermi level is the limit of the chemical potential at zero temperature. You therefore need to calculate it for small positive temperatures before taking the limit, because at zero temperature it is not properly defined.

A simplified model would be to take fermions in two energy levels of respective energy $\epsilon_v<\epsilon_c$ and degeneracy $d_v,d_c$ (two thin bands). The number of fermions is given by Fermi-Dirac statistics:
$$
N = \frac{d_vz}{z+v}+\frac{d_c z}{z+c}
$$
with $v = e^{\beta \epsilon_v},c = e^{\beta \epsilon_c}, z = e^{\beta \mu}$. You can solve exactly the quadratic equation:
$$
(d_v+d_c-N)z^2+((d_c-N)v+(d_v-N)c)z-Nvc = 0
$$
At $N=d_v$, the solution simplifies to:
$$
\begin{align}
z &= \frac{(d_v-d_c)v+\sqrt{(d_v-d_c)^2v^2+4d_vd_cvc}}{2d_c}
\end{align}
$$
You can recover the low temperature asymptotics and in particular the Fermi energy:
$$
\mu=\frac{\epsilon_v+\epsilon_c}{2} +T\ln\frac{d_v}{d_c}
$$
The Fermi energy is therefore the middle of the band gap.

Note that it is true that for $N<d_v$, then $\epsilon_F=\epsilon_v$ and for $N>d_v$, then $\epsilon_F=\epsilon_c$. $\epsilon_F$ is therefore a step function in $N$ and the low temperature limit allows you smooth it out and give a well defined value at the discontinuity.

Hope this helps.